# "Je te le souhaite" vs "je l'espère"

Tags: sens, verbes

I have heard the following dialogue in the TV series Marseille:

- Je sais très bien ce que je fais.
- Je te le souhaite.

The English subtitle translation of the last line is "I hope so". What is the difference between "Je te le souhaite" and "Je l'espère" ?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike *je le souhaite* ("I wish it") or *je l'espère* ("I hope so"), *je **te** le souhaite* means "I hope you do" (literally: "I hope it for you").

The difference is that you are not personally concerned, or at least less concerned than with *je le souhaite*.

Comment: Doesn't "I hope" express that I'm personally concerned? Maybe you meant that "I hope you do" and "je te le souhaite" express more a warning/threat than a true concern ? At least in English, AFAIK the meaning of "I hope you do" depends on voice tone and context.

Comment: *Je te le souhaite* (and I guess "I hope you do") doesn't necessarily express a warning or a threat but imply that whatever happens wouldn't affect that much the person speaking.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. In English AFAIK "I hope so" and "I hope you do" are synonyms and there is no diference in the level of concern between them.

Answer (score -1):

il est difficile de les nuancer sans un contexte précis.Néanmoins il faut noter que je te souhaite peut à l'idée qu'une personne aura un malheur ou un bonheur.tandis qu j'espère peut definir aussi le prémier mais aussi un mot d'ordre.